# Comparator won't flip to HIGH

Tags: comparator

I am learning to use a comparator (LM393N) and running into trouble. No matter what I do, the output is always LOW. I am running off of a 9V battery, and I've added a voltage divider to send half of that to the V- (inverted) pin of the comparator. Yet, whether the non-inverted pin is connected directly to the positive rail (all the way HIGH) or to ground (all the way LOW), the Output pin always reads LOW (0V). What am I doing wrong? Here's a sketch of what I've set up where:

- Pin 4 is inverted pin
- Pin 5 is non-inverted pin
- Pin 3 is positive power source
- Pin 2 is output
- Pin 12 is ground

Sorry for the weird pin numberings! I couldn't figure out how to change it in TinyCAD.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device output is open collector. What this means it that it can either sink current (provide ground) or leave the output at a high impedance state (floating).
You need to add a pull-up resistor from output to the positive supply to force a high voltage level in that floating state.

The value of the pull-up depends on the needs of your circuit. The comparator can sink 6mA min so for 9v you can use a value of about 1.5k and higher.
If the circuit connected to the output doesn't need much current or you just want to experiment you can use a value like 4k7 to 10k (about 1-2mA)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJbGaE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The [LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393.pdf) is open-collector output. You just need a pullup resistor to V+ to make it go high.

[image]

(from datasheet linked above)